# Rest Framework Serializer Method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following Serializer using the [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

This is what I have so far...

**serializer.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    score = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_this_score')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'active', 'score')

    def get_this_score(self, obj):

        profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=19)
        score = [val for val in obj.attribute_answers.all() if val in profile.attribute_answers.all()]
        return (len(score))
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^products/(?P<profile_id>.+)/$', ProductListScore.as_view(), name='product-list-score'),
```

There are a few issues with this snippet of code.

1) The pram pk=19 is hardcoded it should be `self.kwargs['profile_id'].` I have tried and tried, but I don't know how to pass kwarg into the method and cannot get profile_id to work. i.e. I cannot get  it from the url.

2) Should any of this code be in models? I have tried adding to models, but again can pass the args.

**models.py**
 i.e. method class

```
     def get_score(self, profile):

        score = [val for val in self.attribute_answers.all() if val in 
profile.attribute_answers.all()]
            return len(score)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Serializers are passed a context dictionary, which contains the view instance, so you could get the profile_id by doing something like this:

```
view = self.context['view']
profile_id = int(view.kwargs['profile_id'])
```

However in this case I don't think you need to do that as 'obj' will in any case be set to the profile instance.

And yes, you could put the 'get_this_score' method on the model class instead. You'd still need the 'SerializerMethodField', but it would simply call 'return obj.get_this_score(...)', setting any arguments from the serializer context.

Note that the serializer context will also include 'request', so you can also access 'request.user' if needed.

Comment: I like the idea of having this in the models. but SerializerMethodField using source= does not allow me to pass the parms. could you give me an example of using a SerializerMethodField and passing request args plus the object to a model method? this would really help me to understand. Thanks you.

Comment: Im joining to the question of @jason

Comment: in `However in this case I don't think you need to do that as 'obj' will in any case be set to the profile instance` do you mean `Product` instance maybe?

Answer (score 7):

To answer jason's question response to Tom's answer you can access the request object via the same context mechanism like so. You reference the request objects from the ModelMethod definition, you don't pass them. I was able to use this to access the current request.user object as below:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    score = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_this_score')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'active', 'score')

    def get_this_score(self, obj):

        profile = self.context['request'].user
        score = [val for val in obj.attribute_answers.all() if val in profile.attribute_answers.all()]
        return (len(score))
```

Comment: When I am using this serializer with CBV its working fine but when I used this serializer with FBV `return Response({'data':ProductSerializer(user_profiles,many=True).data})` I am getting keyerror request

Comment: solved by [including extra context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)